# MySQL sum() and join in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: a Standings table and a Teams table.

```
Standings has 5 columns: id, teamid, weekid, seasonid, points
Teams has 3 columns: id, name, leagueid
```

I want to get the sum of all points for all standings for a team for all weeks that team has participated in and join it on the id of that team.

I don't know how to do this in a single query, but

```
SELECT sum(s.points), t.name FROM Standings s INNER JOIN Teams t ON s.teamid = t.id WHERE t.leagueid = 1 AND s.seasonid = 1 ORDER BY sum(s.points) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Is kind of what I'm going for.  Thanks.

EDIT:

One of the big problems I'm having is that I'm not actually allowed to access the schema for this, but I'm using this on a test dataset with these sorts of values:

## Team

id  |  name  |  leagueid

1   | alphas |     1

2   |  betas |     1

3   | gammas |     1

## Standing

id  |  teamid  |  weekid  |  seasonid  |  points

(ALPHAS)

1   |    1     |    1     |      1     |    1

2   |    1     |    2     |      1     |    4

3   |    1     |    3     |      1     |    3

(BETAS)

4   |    2     |    1     |      1     |    7

5   |    2     |    2     |      1     |    0

6   |    2     |    3     |      1     |    2

(GAMMAS)

7   |    3     |    1     |      1     |    4

8   |    3     |    2     |      1     |    4

9   |    3     |    3     |      1     |    5

I want the return to be a table looking like:

Name   |   Points

Alphas |   8

Betas  |   9

Gammas |   13

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: It looks to me like your original query is just missing a `GROUP BY t.name` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the columns in selection that are used in having

```
SELECT
  Teams.name,
  SUM(Standings.points) AS StandingPoints,
  Standings.seasonid,
  Teams.leagueid
FROM Teams
  INNER JOIN Standings
    ON Teams.id = Standings.teamid
GROUP BY Teams.id
HAVING Teams.leagueid = 0
    AND Standings.seasonid = 0
ORDER BY StandingPoints DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. When you group by `Teams.id`, it will pick a random `seasonid` from the matches. You should check this in the `WHERE` clause before joining.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Teams.name,
  SUM(Standings.points) AS StandingPoints
FROM Teams
  INNER JOIN Standings
    ON Teams.id = Standings.teamid
WHERE Teams.leagueid = 0
    AND Standings.seasonid = 0
GROUP BY Teams.id
ORDER BY StandingPoints DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think why others are using the HAVING clause for WHERE criteria, so I'll post my version (very like your original):

```
 SELECT t.*
      , s.seasonid
      , SUM(s.points) total
   FROM Team t 
   JOIN Standing s
     ON s.teamid = t.id 
    AND s.seasonid = 1
  WHERE t.leagueid = 1
  GROUP 
     BY t.id
      , s.seasonid
  ORDER
     BY total DESC;
```